# Qt parent widget for Dialog

Tags: qt

Почему если дочернему виджету ставить родителя, то дочерний "вставляется" в родительский? Как этого избежать?

Я просто хочу сделать всплывающий диалог, но при указании родителя он почему то вставляется в него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать сделать так:

```
myDialog->setParent(this); //ну или кто там будет родителем
myDialog->setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog);
```

Ну и соответственно при создании myDialog родителя не указывайте.

Answer (score 1):

> Почему если дочернему виджету ставить родителя, то дочерний "вставляется" в родительский?

Правило из документации - [A widget is clipped by its parent and by the widgets in front of it.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) Вероятно Вам нужно переосмыслить то, что Вы хотите сделать. Попробуйте обратиться к паттернам программирования, например Observer [GoF].

**Update**

У конструктора виджета также есть второй параметр Qt::WindowFlags, который принимает такие значения как Qt::Dialog или Qt::Window [(ref)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html).

Comment: я просто хочу сделать всплывающий диалог, но при указании родителя он почему то вставляется в него.

Comment: У конструктора виджета есть второй параметр Qt::WindowFlags, который принимает такие значения как Qt::Dialog или Qt::Window [(ref)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html). Веротяно это то, что Вам надо.

Comment: У меня диалог был создан на основе QWindget, в этом случае и надо указывать флаг. Если делать на основе QDialog, то все работает нормально.

Comment: @LFDS всплывающий диалог надо наследовать от QDialog, а не от QWidget, тогда будет всплывать отдельным окном, а не помещаться в виджет-родитель